# ZeroMQ word count app gives error when you compile in spark 1.2.1

Tags: scala, streaming, sbt, apache-spark, zeromq

I'm trying to setup zeromq data stream to spark. Basically I took the ZeroMQWordCount.scala app an tried to recompile it and run it.

I have zeromq 2.1 installed, and spark 1.2.1
here is my scala code:

```
package org.apache.spark.examples.streaming

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.actorRef2Scala
import akka.zeromq._
import akka.zeromq.Subscribe
import akka.util.ByteString

import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.zeromq._

import scala.language.implicitConversions
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object ZmqBenchmark {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: ZmqBenchmark <zeroMQurl> <topic>")
      System.exit(1)
    }
    //StreamingExamples.setStreamingLogLevels()
    val Seq(url, topic) = args.toSeq
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ZmqBenchmark")
    // Create the context and set the batch size
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))

    def bytesToStringIterator(x: Seq[ByteString]) = (x.map(_.utf8String)).iterator

    // For this stream, a zeroMQ publisher should be running.
    val lines = ZeroMQUtils.createStream(ssc, url, Subscribe(topic), bytesToStringIterator _)
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
    val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
    wordCounts.print()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

and this is my .sbt file for dependencies:

```
name := "ZmqBenchmark"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "Sonatype (releases)" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark"  %% "spark-streaming" % "1.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-zeromq_2.10" % "1.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.zeromq" %% "zeromq-scala-binding" % "0.0.6"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-zeromq_2.10.0-RC5" % "2.1.0-RC6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-examples_2.10" % "1.1.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.spark-project.zeromq" % "zeromq-scala-binding_2.11" % "0.0.7-spark"
```

The application compiles without any errors using sbt package, however when i run the application with spark submit, i get an error:

```
zaid@zaid-VirtualBox:~/spark-1.2.1$ ./bin/spark-submit --master local[*] ./zeromqsub/example/target/scala-2.10/zmqbenchmark_2.10-1.0.jar tcp://127.0.0.1:5553 hello
15/03/06 10:21:11 WARN Utils: Your hostname, zaid-VirtualBox resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.220.175 instead (on interface eth0)
15/03/06 10:21:11 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/zeromq/ZeroMQUtils$
    at ZmqBenchmark$.main(ZmqBenchmark.scala:78)
    at ZmqBenchmark.main(ZmqBenchmark.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.zeromq.ZeroMQUtils$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 9 more
```

Any ideas why this happens? i know the app should work because when i run the same example using the $/run-example $ script and point to the ZeroMQWordCount app from spark, it runs without the exception. My guess is the sbt file is incorrect, what else do I need to have in the sbt file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ZeroMQUtils.createStream` but the line

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.zeromq.ZeroMQUtils
```

shows that the bytecode for `ZeroMQUtils` was not located. When the spark examples are run, they are run against a jar file (like `spark-1.2.1/examples/target/scala-2.10/spark-examples-1.2.1-hadoop1.0.4.jar`) including the `ZeroMQUtils` class. A solution would be to use the `--jars` flag so `spark-submit` command can find the bytecode. In your case, this could be something like

```
spark-submit --jars /opt/spark/spark-1.2.1/examples/target/scala-2.10/spark-examples-1.2.1-hadoop1.0.4.jar--master local[*] ./zeromqsub/example/target/scala-2.10/zmqbenchmark_2.10-1.0.jar tcp://127.0.0.1:5553 hello
```

assuming that you have installed `spark-1.2.1` in `/opt/spark`.

Comment: Thank you. I have moved on from zeroMQ and using kafka instead. Kafka integration with Spark is much more robust and easier to setup.